# With Powershell, how do I sort a list of count files by date

Tags: powershell

With Powershell, how do I sort a list of count files by date

```
pchost_00364_20160412143516.dat
pchost_00364_20160412144751.dat
pchost_00364_20160412150333.dat
pchost_00364_20160412150452.dat
pchost_00364_20160412151127.dat
pchost_00364_20160412152939.dat
pchost_00364_20160412153029.dat
pchost_00364_20160412153101.dat
pchost_00364_20160412153135.dat
pchost_00364_20160412153215.dat
pchost_00364_20160412160907.dat
pchost_00906_20160412161546.dat
pchost_00907_20160412155312.dat
pchost_00907_20160412155357.dat
pchost_00910_20160412160949.dat
pchost_00916_20160412155545.dat
pchost_00918_20160412144047.dat
pchost_00918_20160412154908.dat
pchost_00940_20160412143732.dat
pchost_00940_20160412150611.dat
pchost_00940_20160412150622.dat
pchost_00940_20160412161126.dat
pchost_00941_20160412143016.dat
pchost_00941_20160412143731.dat
pchost_00941_20160412162005.dat
pchost_00942_20160412155547.dat
pchost_00943_20160412143032.dat
pchost_00943_20160412143200.dat
pchost_00943_20160412143617.dat
pchost_00943_20160412144010.dat
pchost_00943_20160412144704.dat
pchost_00943_20160412145532.dat
pchost_00943_20160412160138.dat
pchost_00951_20160412145544.dat
pchost_00951_20160412161626.dat
pchost_00962_20160412161609.dat
pchost_01529_20160412142948.dat
pchost_01529_20160412143749.dat
pchost_01529_20160412144658.dat
pchost_01529_20160412145010.dat
pchost_01529_20160412150214.dat
pchost_01529_20160412150630.dat
pchost_01529_20160412150848.dat
pchost_01529_20160412151925.dat
pchost_01529_20160412161840.dat
pchost_03494_20160412142929.dat
pchost_03494_20160412144528.dat
pchost_03494_20160412144718.dat
pchost_03494_20160412155340.dat
pchost_03499_20160412154603.dat
pchost_03964_20160412144550.dat
pchost_03964_20160412160336.dat
pchost_04152_20160412145420.dat
pchost_04872_20160412161618.dat
```

Comment: can you use filesystem information like lastwritetime or do you need to use the timestamp from the filename

Answer (score 1):

many different ways to do it. here is one example

```
$files = @'
pchost_03964_20160412160336.dat
pchost_04152_20160412145420.dat
'@ -split "`n"

$files | sort {$_.substring($_.lastindexof('_'))}
```

here is another option based on your comment

```
$files = @'
name
pchost_03964_20160412160336.dat
pchost_04152_20160412145420.dat
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$results = foreach ($file in $files) {
    $split = $file.name.Split('_ ')
    $date = $split[2].Substring(0, $split[2].IndexOf('.'))
    $year = $date.Substring(0, 4)
    $month = $date.Substring(4, 2)
    $day = $date.Substring(6, 2)
    $hour = $date.Substring(8, 2)
    $minute = $date.Substring(10, 2)
    $second = $date.Substring(12, 2)
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $split[1]
        Date = "$year $month $day"
        HMS = "$hour$minute$second"
    }
}

$results | group name, date | % {
    $group = $_.group | sort date, hms -Descending | select -f 1
    $date = $group.date, $group.hms -join ' '
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Count = $_.Count
        Name = $group.name
        Date = $date
    }
} | sort date
```

Comment: no i want this list : 
name      count     date
---------- ---------- ---------
03964 >> 5 >> 2016 04 12 
04152 >> 2 >> 2016 04 12
.
.
.

Comment: I have a folder that contains several dat file extension and I want to calculate the number apartir file name that are on the file name and date of the file like this
pchost_00907_20160412155312.dat
pchost_00907_20160413155357.dat
pchost_00910_20160401160949.dat
pchost_00916_20160412155545.dat
pchost_00918_20160412144047.dat
pchost_00918_20160412154908.dat
pchost_00940_20160412143732.dat
pchost_00940_20160402150611.dat
pchost_00940_20160412150622.dat
pchost_00940_20160412161126.dat
...
for exp search by date param 160412 poster like this
907> 1
916> 1
918> 2
940> 3
..